# NSImage to Base64 string loses quality

Tags: swift, cocoa, base64, nsimage

I'm trying to convert an NSImage from an NSImageView to a Base64 string but end up losing half the quality when decoding the output.

The code to convert to Base64 seems straightforward enough which I've put into an NSString extension:

```
extension NSImage {

    func base64String() -> String? {
        guard
            let bits = self.representations.first as? NSBitmapImageRep,
            let data = bits.representation(using: .JPEG, properties: [:])
        else {
            return nil
        }

        return "data:image/jpeg;base64,\(data.base64EncodedString())"
    }
}
```

Trying that with a test JPG image that's 39KB gets decoded back to 20KB. I've tried converting the same image using online tools and get a perfect encode -> decode.

Other code I've tried:

```
func base64String() -> String? {
    let cgImgRef = self.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
    let bmpImgRef = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: cgImgRef!)
    let data = bmpImgRef.representation(using: NSBitmapImageFileType.JPEG, properties: [:])!
    return "data:image/jpeg;base64,\(data.base64EncodedString())"
}
```

Which results in a 17KB file.

Any help would be very much appreciated as I've racked my brain with this for hours.

Comment: If possible, rather than taking some asset, converting to a `NSImage`, and then converting back, grab the original asset. To grab a JPEG, convert to a `NSImage`, and then convert back to a JPEG will make the asset larger or involve quality loss (depending upon your settings). To use PNG will be faithful, compressed file, but probably still larger than the original JPEG. If at all possible, keep the `NSData`/`Data` for the original asset and use that (unless you're marking it up or otherwise editing it).

Comment: Appreciate the reply but it's slightly trickier. The image comes from an Image Well (as an NSImageView), so I have no raw access to the asset other than what I can get from the NSImage. The image that is dropped into the image well then goes off to an API as a base64 string. Do you know a way I can get the raw data from an NSImageView without having to `represent` it as some file type?

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified the compression value so it defaults to the default compression. To have no compression use the code below:

```
let data = bits.representation(using: .JPEG, properties: [NSImageCompressionFactor:1.0])
```

Comment: Seems to have gone the opposite way now - 51KB from 39. Is there a way to use the original?

Comment: That could be an asset considerably larger than the original JPEG. No, you cannot get the "original". You should save the original asset when you first loaded it, and not attempt to reconstruct it from the `NSImage`.

Comment: The issue I have is it's going off to an API that takes it as a string among other data. Ideally would like to do multi-part form but I have no control over the backend unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsbitmapimagerep), `NSBitmapImageRep` renders the image. Your code seems to re-encode the image as *jpeg* again. As *jpeg* is a loosy algorithm, this will result in loss of quality. You can try to:

- use *png* as representation
- use a high (or 1.0) compression factor for *jpeg*.

Comment: Yep, PNG is decent, lossless compression. JPEG @ 1.0 can generate very large assets.

Comment: Tried PNG also but results in 3x file size. The images will be headshots and generated thumbnails which would result in slow load times